# Android comparison of layout sizing techniques between device sizes

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a relatively new app programmer, largely self-taught over the last year.

From the beginning I naturally went down the path of sizing the UI using percentages in the xml files where possible.  And where this wasn't possible I calculated screen metrics at runtime and calculated dimensions based on a percentage of these screen metrics.  So each time I change the UI I only have to change one number.

This has worked quite well, giving consistency between the array of android devices.  Although I recognize this could run into performance problems if there are a large number of objects that need sized at runtime.

Recently I've read more about using the multiple dimens.xml files to size the UI based on the 'size class' of the device.  this seems the method most commonly used on android.

To me this method seems less efficient.  You have to alter perhaps 3 or 4 dimen.xml files every time you change the UI.  On top of that a dimen.xml file for large devices can cover a wide array of screen metrics, creating inconsistency between devices.  The main gain seems to be better performance.

So my question is which method is better? Is the performance trade off worth the consistency, and time saved in making alterations to the UI?
Or alternatively is there a better method that you could suggest?

Comment: This is kind of a broad question.You have a lot of techniques availablelike several dimens.xml files, several layout folders, using weight in a LinearLayout, modifying the number of columns in a gridView... a lot of possibilities depending on what you need to achieve

Comment: Thanks there are a couple of techniques there I hadn't heard of so I'll do some more reading!

Answer (score 0):

To make your app supports multiple screen,you have to follow this method.like

1.create 5 folders like(layout-hdpi,layout-ldpi,layout-mdpi,layout-xhdpi,layout-xxhdpi)

2.copy your layout folder and paste it into these all folder

3.then open your xml file

4.then you have to select mobile like(Nexus One,Nexus 5,Nexus 10)which is what size you want

5.the corresponding xml file will open while selecting mobile

6.then finally you have to design for that corresponding size

(Note: you should design one xml for all mobile.then run your application.it will support all screen)

I hope this one will Help you :)

Comment: here you don't need to calculate any pixel for screen size.This is easy and best way to support multiple screen application

Comment: I understand that this is one way to support multiple screens, but is it the best way? creating 5 layout files is a lot of legwork especially when making small changes to your UI.

Comment: # enciyaa: (http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) check this link

Comment: #encyiaa:You have a lot of techniques available.but all of them won't give accurate result compare than this.So this one is easy and bast way to get accurate result